# create png image with php from an URL

Tags: php, png

How to create PNG image with given width and height from an image URL. i was trying with this code. but getting an invalid picture:

```
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
header('Content-type: image/png');
@imagepng($dst_r, url_to_save, $jpeg_quality);
```

Answer (score 0):

First i would fetch the file from url (file_get_contents/curl/etc) then write it to disk and find out if it's an image, what type etc, then, i would cut my efforts and use an image manipulation library, like http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/ to resize the image and save it as i want.

Comment: actually i am working cropping (jCrop). i am cropping from an already uploaded png image and trying to save the cropped one.